# is there any way to install dependency from multiple package.json files for monorepo projects in npm

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, dependencies, monorepo

I have a distribution folder which contains the root package.json file and sub projects. Ex project1, project2, etc. I want to pack it as a tarball tgz file. Now when anyone install package from tgz file it should install all the dependency from project1, project2, etc. Currently it's just installing root package.json's dependency.

Answer (score 1):

Hm, you can take a look at this cli: https://github.com/lerna/lerna

From their doc:

> #### What does a Lerna repo look like? There's actually very little to it.
>
> You have a file structure that looks like this:
>
> [image]